# Homebrew up-to-date, but do I need to worry about `could not link` + `delete path` errors?

Tags: bash, unix, homebrew

I've used homebrew to install rvm and ocaml packages successfully, but I've always wondered about the errors at the end of `$ brew update` output. For example, when I ran it just now the bash output was:

```
Error: Could not link:
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew

Please delete these paths and run `brew update`.
Error: Could not link:
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew

Please delete these paths and run `brew update`.
Error: Could not link:
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew

Please delete these paths and run `brew update`.
Error: Could not link:
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew-cask.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
```

My colleagues say not to worry about it, but... I worry about it. What can I do to fix them? Just run `rm` and completely obliterate the "delete me" paths, and `mkdir` the paths that cannot be linked?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All the specified files are just symlinks, so don't worry, just remove them.

To make sure that they are symlinks, you can run this:

```
file -h <what you want to inspect>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reassurance. I did a bit of reading about symlinks and then deleted them `rm -rf /path`

Comment: `brew update` runs clean now
`Updated 1 tap (caskroom/cask).
No changes to formulae.`

Comment: Ah, thank you. Did not know that grey checkmark was clickable!

Comment: Well, I forgot that's gray before clicking.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
../usr/local/..$rm -rf /usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
```

and then

```
../usr/local/..$brew upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try to remove the path which showed on your terminal

$ rm -rf [path]

Example:
$ rm -rf /usr/local/share/doc/homebrew

Answer (score 0):

rm -rf FILE_NAME

In your case it should be as follows

rm -rf /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew

rm -rf /usr/local/share/doc/homebrew

rm -rf /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
 and so on